# Por que o onLocationChanged do LocationListener é tão impreciso?

Tags: android, gps

Estou trabalhando com o gps do Android. Estou utilizando o `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` e ele está me dando pontos muito ruins, muito longe da minha localização. Alguém já trabalhou com essa ferramenta? é normal? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 2):

A precisão real de um dispositivo depende do chipset, da localização onde você se encontra 
( em um lugar fechado, tende se a ser mais impreciso), entre outras. 
 Todos os locais gerados pelo LocationManager incluem uma precisão:
  [getAccuracy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy())

Esta é informada com 68% de confiança!

Normalmente, a precisão de um dispositivo é dada como uma distância juntamente 
com a percentagem de medições que estão dentro da distância de que a verdadeira localização.

A precisão típica de um dispositivo GPS de mão seria algo como 30% das suas medidas no prazo de 50 metros 
da posição real (sim, os dispositivos são tipicamente que imprecisa).

Para que se tenha algo mais preciso, considere usar apenas Locations mais precisas :

```
 if(location.getAccuracy() < 25.0){
 // Usamos esta localização
}
```

Comment: Thiago possui algum link para este dados? É algo do meu interesse =)

Comment: Está na resposta! segue : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()